# Kalman Filter module to correct ARIMA forecast result

Tags: python, forecasting, kalman-filter

I am currently writing a script to do a wind speed forecast using ARIMA and I have pretty nice results for a very short term forecast. 
I was wondering which of the Kalman Filter function in python is the one that would allow me to have lower root mean square error of my forecast.
I am using only wind speed as input data and I want to see some improvements in my forecast errors.
Can you give me some guidelines on which module to use, functions and be a little bit specific on why I can't use others.
Do I have to use pykalman (kalman smoother)?Why?How?
Or tsa.kalmanf.kalmanfilter (In this module I am seeing two different types of Kalman Filter: one with the k in capital and there is no comments on the function and the other in non capital letters)
Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I would use this [numpy implementation on the scipy wiki](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/KalmanFiltering):

```
# Kalman filter example demo in Python

# A Python implementation of the example given in pages 11-15 of "An
# Introduction to the Kalman Filter" by Greg Welch and Gary Bishop,
# University of North Carolina at Chapel Hill, Department of Computer
# Science, TR 95-041,
# http://www.cs.unc.edu/~welch/kalman/kalmanIntro.html

# by Andrew D. Straw

import numpy
import pylab

# intial parameters
n_iter = 50
sz = (n_iter,) # size of array
x = -0.37727 # truth value (typo in example at top of p. 13 calls this z)
z = numpy.random.normal(x,0.1,size=sz) # observations (normal about x, sigma=0.1)

Q = 1e-5 # process variance

# allocate space for arrays
xhat=numpy.zeros(sz)      # a posteri estimate of x
P=numpy.zeros(sz)         # a posteri error estimate
xhatminus=numpy.zeros(sz) # a priori estimate of x
Pminus=numpy.zeros(sz)    # a priori error estimate
K=numpy.zeros(sz)         # gain or blending factor

R = 0.1**2 # estimate of measurement variance, change to see effect

# intial guesses
xhat[0] = 0.0
P[0] = 1.0

for k in range(1,n_iter):
    # time update
    xhatminus[k] = xhat[k-1]
    Pminus[k] = P[k-1]+Q

    # measurement update
    K[k] = Pminus[k]/( Pminus[k]+R )
    xhat[k] = xhatminus[k]+K[k]*(z[k]-xhatminus[k])
    P[k] = (1-K[k])*Pminus[k]

pylab.figure()
pylab.plot(z,'k+',label='noisy measurements')
pylab.plot(xhat,'b-',label='a posteri estimate')
pylab.axhline(x,color='g',label='truth value')
pylab.legend()
pylab.xlabel('Iteration')
pylab.ylabel('Voltage')

pylab.figure()
valid_iter = range(1,n_iter) # Pminus not valid at step 0
pylab.plot(valid_iter,Pminus[valid_iter],label='a priori error estimate')
pylab.xlabel('Iteration')
pylab.ylabel('$(Voltage)^2$')
pylab.setp(pylab.gca(),'ylim',[0,.01])
pylab.show()
```

A common [misconception regarding the filter is that noise need be distributed normally](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter). This is not required.

Hope this helps and if you require further explanation, do leave a comment.

Comment: And what about the kalman filter functions already in python library?
I am talking about pykalman and the one in statsmodels (tsa.kalmanf.kalmanfilter).

Comment: :)
Is there any preanalysis required before using Kalman filter as to check if our time series in non linear in order to know which module to use (extended kalman filter)?

Comment: Not sure about other implementations of it.

Comment: Per your second comment, I'd refer you to Stark and Wood, "Probability and Random Processes with Applications to Signal Processing". Using the kalman filter is not for the faint of heart, after all.

Comment: What do you think of this module (kalman filter code intended for use with the ARMA model : http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.kalmanf.kalmanfilter.KalmanFilter.html)

I have been using ARIMA (include integration, for non stationary time series) and I was wondering if it suits!

Comment: Finally the right module to use is pykalman.
In pykalman , we have to import _filter_correct from pykalman.KalmanFilter. But I still have issues with a parameter (input) that I did not understand which is observation offset